# How do I disable an iframe from scrolling by editing the referenced page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Is there a way to disable the scrollwheel for a page that's being referenced by an iframe?
I'm trying to use an iframe to reference a site that I've made, but changing the iframe's scrolling attribute to no doesn't disable the scrollwheel.
Is there some css I can use in referenced page so that an iframe that references it won't have a scroll wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Add `scrolling="no"` in iframe

```html
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/" scrolling="no" width="300px" height="500px"></iframe>
```